# How to handle JsValue in Scala/Play

Tags: scala, api, playframework, jsvalue

I'm trying to learn Scala/Play so I created a sample api that uses WSRequest to connect to GitHub and returns some info based on the user's id. I can convert this response to JsValue by doing:

```
val response: JsValeu = result.json
Ok(json)
```

I am having trouble when trying to manipulate the JsValue, for example filter values based on some criteria, etc? Do I need to convert it to a JsObject? I've looked on the Play documentation but I can't figure out how to do this.

What is the approach when handling JsValue?

Thanks

Comment: Start with https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaJson and describe more precisely what you want to do

Comment: Ok(json).as("application/javascript; charset=utf-8")

Comment: Where is your problem, do you want to convert your response val into some case class?  and you don't know how to use JSON Reads/Writes/Format combinators

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JsValue signifies any sort of JSON data entity, including objects, numbers, strings, etc.

If you want to filter values in a JsObject, then you'll have to "cast" your JsValue into a JsObject. like:

`val jsonObject: JsObject = response.as[JsObject]`

Then you can mutate the object how you like.

Read the documentation on JsObject and JsValue to find out how to do the rest of what you're trying to do.

- https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.libs.json.JsObject
- https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.libs.json.JsValue